# Using Vue refs with Pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, reactive-programming, pinia

I am trying to use a [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) state store to keep an object which uses [Vue refs](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) inside it.

The object is an instance of this class (simplified example):

```js
class Foo {
    
    constructor() {
        this.field = ref('')
    }

    setField(value) {
        this.field.value = value
    }

}

const foo = new Foo
foo.setField('bar') // all happy — no errors here
```

(I use those kind of objects as data records, and the fields need to be refs because they are rendered in templates and I want them reactive).

So, I define a Pinia store and set the object to it:

```js
const useState = defineStore('main', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      foo: null
    }
  }
})

const state = useState()
state.foo = foo
```

Now, when I try to operate on the object having retrieved it from the store, I get:

```js
state.foo.setField('baz') // this fails with the error
```

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'value' on string 'bar'
```

What I guess happens here is that Pinia dereferences the `field` property on the `foo` object when it is accessed from the store. But heck, I do not need that! I want the `foo` object behave consistently no matter where it is retrieved from.

Any idea how to do that? I see Pinia has a method called [`skipHydrate`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/modules/pinia.html#skiphydrate) which might be about this stuff, but I can't find how to use it.

Comment: foo is null in current store implementation

Comment: @EstusFlask Initially yes it is `null`, but then I do `state.foo = foo`. It is no longer `null` after that, in fact `state.foo instanceof Foo` returns `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pinia uses Vue composition API internally and shares its behaviour.

As the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive) says,

> The reactive conversion is "deep": it affects all nested properties. A
> reactive object also deeply unwraps any properties that are refs while
> maintaining reactivity.
>
> It should also be noted that there is no ref unwrapping performed when
> the ref is accessed as an element of a reactive array or a native
> collection type like Map.
>
> To avoid the deep conversion and only retain reactivity at the root
> level, use shallowReactive() instead.

In order to keep class instance intact, `markRaw` can be used:

```
  state: () => {
    return {
      foo: markRaw(new Foo())
    }
  }
```

It may be unnecessary to explicitly use composition API like `ref` in class implementation; instead class instance can be made reactive as is with `reactive(new Foo())` with notable exceptions (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050924/3731501) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67895251/3731501)).

Comment: +1 for `markRaw`, will try that. Not sure about using `reactive(new Foo())` as the real `Foo` also uses `computed`, `watch` etc. in its constructor.

Comment: @Greendrake Then it probably doesn't need to be a class at all because it won't benefit from oop that much, composition is fp-oriented. `reactive` is for classes that weren't specifically designed as reactive.

Comment: `Foo` represents a data record. It does extend another class which provides stuff like triggering and listening to events (and, potentially, persistence in remote store etc.). So, there _is_ a good use of OOP here. Not sure why composition necessarily needs to be deemed fp-oriented if it works with OOP just fine.