# How to make a class getter reactive in Vue.js 3 with Composition API?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, class, properties, reactive

I'm trying to make a class instance property reactive to display the error message if authentication fails.

**userModel.ts**

```
export class User {
  private error: string;

  set errorMessage(errorMessage: string) {
    this.error = errorMessage;
  }
  get errorMessage() {
    return this.error
  }

// other stuff...
}
```

**LoginView.vue**

```
import { User } from "./models/userModel";
import { ref } from 'vue';

const user = new User();
const errorMessage = ref(user.errorMessage); // <--- This is not working.
const errorMessage = ref(user.error); // <--- Neither this even if user.error property is public.
```

No warnings or exceptions, reactive value just remains empty. What I am missing?

Comment: You should probably avoid setting only some properties of an object to be reactive and instead have the whole object be reactive.

const user = reactive(new User);

but if you insist on making this work, I figure the error must be elsewhere, since I reacreated your example and it works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, you are creating new reactive variables, with the initial value being the one in your class. Your class and your `ref` are unrelated.

If you want your class to have reactive properties, you have to instanciate them this way:

```js
export class User {
  private error: Ref<string> = ref('');

  public errorMessage: WritableComputedRef<string> = computed({
    get() {
      return this.error.value
    },
    set(errorMessage: string) {
      this.error.value = errorMessage;
    },
  })
}
```

---

Side note: I'd recommend to use the "composables" approach instead of using classes, because class instances are not compatible with SSR.

```js
export function useUser () {
  const user: User = reactive({})
  // other stuff...

  const error: Ref<string> = ref('');

  const errorMessage: WritableComputedRef<string> = computed({
    get() {
      return this.error.value
    },
    set(errorMessage: string) {
      this.error.value = errorMessage;
    },
  })

  return { user, errorMessage }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Kapcash. Have you defined your own 'Reactive' type here? I can't find it in the framework's API.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remember the correct type. I updated the code with the correct types. `reactive` returns a `UnwrapNestedRefs` which is just a fancy type to say it's a `User` without any `Ref` inside.

Comment: Notice that the use of composition API inside a class is a workaround that may cause more problems than it solves. This not just about reactive types. If `User` instance becomes reactive, e.g as a property of reactive object like a store, , `user` ref property is unwrapped. There will be `this.error`, not `this.error.value`, and errorMessage implementation becomes invalid

Comment: The computed way of using class property really helped. I have been trying all kind of tricks to have internal ref but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: I needed a `WritableComputedRef` instead of a `ComputedRef`

Answer (score 4):

Accessing a primitive property by value like `ref(user.error)` can't be reactive, no matter it's a getter or not, in this case it doesn't differ from `ref(undefined)`.

For own enumerable property it could be:

```
let user = reactive(new User());
let { error } = toRefs(user);
```

It won't handle property accessors, they need to be explicitly accessed with computed property:

```
let errorMessage = computed({
  get: () => user.errorMessage,
  set: value => { user.errorMessage = value }
});
```

Whether it's a getter or regular property doesn't affect how a computed works because an accessor is defined on class prototype and accesses reactive `this.error` (this can be a problem when non-reactive `this` is bound in a constructor, like is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69050412/vue-composition-api-and-reactive-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894487/vue-3-reactivity-not-triggered-from-inside-a-class-instance)).