# Vue class objects with internal ref breaks with reactive

Tags: typescript, vue.js, reactive-programming

First of all, I love Vue 3. I really enjoy it over many other frameworks. But I think I have found a limitation. I am trying to wrap some of my very complicated logic in `class` where internally each instance does the dirty work. This feels more natural for me. But when my instances are wrapped with `reactive()`, everything seems to break.

Here is an example:

```
export class Container {
  public stat: Ref<Stat> = ref({ cpu: 0 });
  private _throttledStatHistory: UseThrottledRefHistoryReturn<Stat, Stat>;

  constructor(
    public readonly id: string,
    // more fields not shown...
  ) {
    this._throttledStatHistory = useThrottledRefHistory(this._stat, { capacity: 300, deep: true, throttle: 1000 });
  }

  public statHistory: ComputedRef<UseRefHistoryRecord<Stat>[]> = computed(
    () => this._throttledStatHistory.history.value
  );
}
```

I can use this object with something like

```
const container = new Container("123")
container.stat.value = { cpu: 1}
container.stat.value = { cpu: 2}
```

However, when using reactive like so:

```
const myRef = reactive(new Container("123"))
```

Everything seems to break:

```
myRef.value.stat.value // stat is no longer a ref. It is now a proxy
myRef.value.stat.value = {cpu: 3} // also breaks as statHistory is not updated at all
```

My assumption is that everything being wrapped in `reactive` breaks.

Somethings can be fixed with `toRaw()` like `toRaw(myRef.value).stat.value = ...` but that feels unnatural.

Note if I make `stat` private with  `private stat: Ref<Stat> = ref({ cpu: 0 });` then the problem still persists. I expected private members to not be affected by `reactive`.

I am going crazy debugging this. What is the proper way to do class with internal reactivity?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73163014/how-to-make-a-class-getter-reactive-in-vue-js-3-with-composition-api

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69050412/vue-composition-api-and-reactive-class . This idea is faulty by design. Vue reactivity wasn't designed to be used with classes, you won't benefit from using them instead of plain objects. `ref(new Container("123"))` - can be solved with shallowRef, but this is just a symptom of a bigger problem

Comment: Thanks. I saw those already. The problem is a little different because I am seeing my refs being converted to regular proxies which is unexpected.

Comment: I think you're right though. Vue wasn't designed for this use case. Which is unfortunate. I may have to figure out a way to move all the reactivity of `stat` to outside.

Comment: Your problem can be seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73163509/3731501 . It's expected and documented, https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-reactive-objects . You'll have less problems when rewriting Container to regular composable function. Nothing here really requires a class.

Comment: So I was already using that solution with `computed`. Still didn't work. But reading the doc I found that it is documented for `reactive` to unwrap all refs. That's good to see. Then I saw `shallowRef` as you suggested and `markRaw`. I am going to play with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Estus for suggestions.

Looks like there are two options that worked for me:

1. Use shallow reactive like

```
const myRef = shallowReactive(new Container("123"))
```

This works, but the con is that all my other code needs to be aware of using shallow.

2. Use `markRaw`

```
export class Container {
  public stat: Ref<Stat>;
  private throttledStatHistory: UseThrottledRefHistoryReturn<Stat, Stat>;

  constructor(
    public readonly id: string,
    // skipped
  ) {
    this.stat = markRaw(ref({ cpu: 0, memory: 0, memoryUsage: 0 }));
    this.throttledStatHistory = markRaw(
      useThrottledRefHistory(this.stat, { capacity: 300, deep: true, throttle: 1000 })
    );
  }

  public getStatHistory() {
    return this.throttledStatHistory.history.value;
  }
}
```

I liked the second option because it doesn't depend on shallow being used properly.