# Handling reactive typescript objects in vue 3 that contain Refs

Tags: vue.js, proxy, reactive, vue-composition-api, ref

I am trying to use the Composition API of vue 3, and struggle to handle reactive typescript objects. As I understand from the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive), when you make an object reactive, `vue` wraps it and all nested objects into a `Proxy` and converts all `Ref`s to `Proxies` as well.

The problem is that when you have a chain of nested method calls, only the first of them is invoked on `Proxy` wrapper (see the [attached diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM5ER.jpg) for an example), and all of the remaining ones are invoked on standard typescript objects.

This inconsistency makes developing an app really hard - I have to basically support two versions of each method dealing with references - one for calling on `Proxy` and one for calling on a normal instance + check object types in runtime. There is not a word about such problem in the documentation. Am I right in my attempts to solve this problem, or should I throw an exception when some methods are not invoked as expected, or there is a better way of solving this issue?

[example: dependency diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM5ER.jpg)

I've tried to implement a typescript object, the methods of which can be called through both - reactive and non-reactive contexts.

I expected the object to handle Refs consistently regardless of whether it is called from reactive or non-reactive context.

In reality, **when context is reactive, current object is actually a `Proxy`, and all properties typed as `Ref`s are also `Proxies`, so I don't have to call `value` property on them to access their members**. However, **when the context is not reactive, all properties typed as `Ref`s remain `Ref`s and I have to go through their `value` property before accessing their nested members**.

Comment: "I expected the object to handle Refs consistently" -  the expectation is wrong, this is basic and documented behaviour, it's generally preferable with regular composition api usage https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-reactive-objects . It's the use of classes that is primary problem here, you'll have to jump through hoops to use them efficiently, some points are here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76247596/3731501

Comment: As for the specific problem with corge ref, it can be solved with # native private field and a pair of class getter setters if it needs to be accessed publicly, so it would be ignored by vue class reactivity. But it's a point solution to a bigger problem