# TS + Vue: ref boolean becomes just a boolean after construct

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have this code:

```
export default class Some{
    private isUpdating: Ref<boolean> = ref(false)
    ....
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.isUpdating) //it shows RefImpl
    }
    async update() {
         console.log(this.isUpdating) //it shows simple boolean...
         this.isUpdating.value = true //...so this causes error
         ...some work
         this.isUpdating.value = false
    }
}
```

There no other modifications of this variable. Tried also initialize it in constructor method, but result is always the same: in constructor this variable is ref, after initialization it becomes simple boolean. Where am i wrong?

Comment: This is a known class pitfall. Avoid using this in constructor and refs. You can use a ref as native private # field in order to not unwrap it. I'd suggest to not use reactive classes at all as Vue isn't suited well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76247596/3731501 for an overview