# Using classes to hold state in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

**Context**

I am building a Vue 3 application using Pinia for state management

On my `login page` I am creating a Pinia store to hold its state, like this:

```
export const useLogInStore = defineStore("logInStore", () => {
  const logInSession = new AuthLogInSession();

  return {
     logInSession 
   }
})
```

Along with some other code the Pinia store contains an `AuthLogInSession` class instance which holds the state and logic of the actual log-in process. It looks like this:

```
export class AuthLogInSession {

   email = ref<string>("");
   password = ref<string>("");

   constructor() {}

   isValid = computed<boolean>(() => {
      const isPasswordValid = this.password.value.length > 0;
      const isEmailValid = this.email.value.length > 0;
      return isPasswordValid && isEmailValid;
   });

   async logIn() {
      return await signInByEmailAndPassword(
      this.email.value,
      this.password.value);
   }
}
```

In my template I am simply using this class's properties to update the UI. Here is a simple example of this:

```
<script setup>
import { useLogInStore } from "~/stores/auth/login";

const logInStore = useLogInStore();
</script>
<template>
  <button :disabled="!loginStore.logInSession.isValid"> Log in </button>
</template>
```

**Question**

As I see it, there are two approaches to this.

1. Do as I did in my example, by using a class to hold state and logic
2. Skip the separate class altogether, and instead put state and logic in the Pinia store directly.

I have [read](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/aosbfu/how_can_i_make_an_es6_class_reactive_when_used_in/) that approach 1 is bad practice as classes shouldn't be used in this way in Vue 3. As I understood it, reactivity can be hard to achieve then. Still, I do find approach 1 pretty neat as it keeps things separate, especially for more complex use cases.

My question is which approach should be used? Are there potential problems with them? Perhaps someone has taken one of them and could share their experience with that approach?

Comment: It's OOP for the OOP's sake. Stick to 2. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76247596/3731501 , there are several good reasons to not use classes for reactivity in Vue, and no real one to do that.