# How can I detect when a property is modified from inside the class?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 and Action Cable.

I need to monitor my WebSocket connection.
I wanted to make my subscription reactive so that I could watch the `subscription.consumer.connection.disconnected` field, but this doesn't work.
When I tried to dig deeper, I found out that everything inside the `subscription` variable is reactive and if I change the `disconnected` field manually, everything works as intended, but if that `disconnected` field is modified inside the `Connection` class, that class knows nothing about reactivity and I don't get any updates.

Can this be solved anyhow, or my only option is to hook to the subscription "connected/disconnected" events?

Here is a sample code:

TestClass.ts

```
export class TestClass {
    state = 'connected'

    constructor() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.state = 'disconnected'
        }, 5000)
    }
}
```

TestView.vue

```
<template>
<div></div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {TestClass} from "@/core/test/testClass";

const test = ref(new TestClass())
watch(() => test.value.state, (newVal) => {
  console.log('watch fired', newVal)
}, {deep: true})

</script>
```

`watch` never fired

However, if I modify the test class like this:

```
export class TestClass {
    state = 'new'

    constructor() {
        this.state = 'connected'
    }

    run() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            debugger;
            this.state = 'disconnected'
        }, 5000)
    }
}
```

and call `run()` after making the class reactive, everything works.
I'll keep digging

Comment: You can make a class reactive but with several restrictions https://stackoverflow.com/a/76247596/3731501 . It's unknown if it's feasible in your case because you didn't show code

Comment: @EstusFlask, thank you. I added an example. The class uses ```this``` in the constructor. Thus, it is not reactive. I added another example that works. if I inspect ```this``` in my example, it is a Proxy. But ```this``` in the action cable class is not a proxy. Weird. I'll keep digging. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894487/vue-3-reactivity-not-triggered-from-inside-a-class-instance . You need to write a class in a way it's compatible with vue reactivity

Comment: @EstusFlask, the thing is that I can't rewrite Action Cable classes. But they seem to comply with vue reactivity. I'll post the solution when I find it

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. The change comes from a Websocket event handler that uses ```this``` and was set before the object was made reactive. Not sure how to solve this. I can't make my Action Cable consumer reactive from the very beginning

Comment: Not sure how this can be solved in your case, consider posting the whole thing with relevant parts. Sometimes class hierarchy can be hacked to fit your needs. Probably not the best approach, using the events and storing the state in global store would be ok and not hacky

Comment: @EstusFlask, I solved it by creating a wrapper for the Action Cable subscription and handling its events, updating wrapper properties.