VueJS/Typescript - define reactive values in typescript class
I've came across the idea, defining ref() or computed values etc. in an external class for having a cleaner code structure and less overloaded .vue file.
For Example i have a test.ts file like this.
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import type { Ref, ComputedRef } from "vue";

export class Test {
    public refValue: Ref<number> = ref(0)
    public compValue: ComputedRef<string> = computed(() => {
        if (this.refValue.value === 0) return 'No Value given'
        else return `Value is ${this.refValue.value}`
    })

    constructor() {}

    public init() {
        this.refValue.value = 10
    }

}

And a Test.vue file like this
<template>
  <div v-if="test">
    <span>{{ test.refValue }}</span>
    <span>{{ test.compValue }}</span>
  </div>
<template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Test } from './Test.ts'
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

const test = ref<Test | null>(null)

onMounted(() => {
  test.value = new Test()
  test.value.init()
})
</script>

I've tried this example and the .ts file just deletes the ref() assigned to the refValue and assigns the value to it.
( refValue = 0 )
In this case at the init() there would be an Type error because there is no 'value' in 0.
So here my question: Is this possible doing it this way and when it is, what am i doing wrong?
( Source : VueJS.org )

I'd suggest to just not use reactive classes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76247596/3731501 .Their use isn't justified in most cases including this one. You can avoid this with gimmicks as shallowRef, markRaw, etc, but in the end they are just faulty by design

Does this answer your question? Unwrapping of a ref variable declared in a class - vue3

See Vue Docs - ref() will unwrap nested refs. It means:
ref({
  refValue: ref(0),
  __proto__: Test,
})

// equals to
ref({
  refValue: 0,
  __proto__: Test,
})

So this.refValue = 0.
You can use shallowRef to avoid this behavior.
demo
