In VSCode, ts-plugin complains about computed property with the setter
The property myValue is defined like this:
export class MyClass {
  myValue: string;
}
export const useSomeStore = defineStore('someStore', () => {
  const myClass = ref(new MyClass());

  const myValue = computed({
    get() {
      return myClass.value.myValue;
    },
    set(value: string) {
      myClass.value.myValue = value;
    }
  });
}

When the property is used like this:
const someStore = useSomeStore();
someStore.myValue = "hello";

in VSCode there's an error:

Cannot assign to 'myValue' because it is a read-only property. ts-plugin(2540)

While in reality the property is assigned correctly.
So I want to know:

Does the error actually point to some issue (i.e. even though property assignment works, there's another reason TS is complaining)? Or is it incorrect?
And how can I avoid or suppress the error for this specific line? (I don't want to disable such error globally)


I see it's better to keep the store state encapsulated and just expose the necessary setters to update the inner state

The question doesn't mention this, but you seem to use pinia store, which is a completely different case in terms of TS types rather than using just a computed. I'd suggest to stick to the official way a store is supposed to be defined. It's unlikely that you will find the use of a writable computed in pinia docs, this is orthogonal to how stores work (any complex mutations are done in actions). FWIW classes cause problems with vue reactivity on a constant basis, their use is not justified here, so you could end up with a more simple way to write it that doesn't cause this problem

@EstusFlask I've simplified question as much as possible. In reality I have 2 different routes, which reuse the same 3rd-party integration (which consists of quite a few functions), currently encapsulated in a class. That is: route X components -> use storeX -> uses that class; route Y components -> use storeY -> uses same integration. Probably a different question, but if you have a suggestion how to express a common set of functions to be reused by 2 different features, will be happy to hear. Seems composable not suitable here, since stores (and not components) are reusing this functionality

A composable makes sense, it's basically a reusable function that uses reactivity api. You could name it differently than "use" to designate the purpose, but I don't see the problem here, a developer needs to be aware of the context where a composable is used any way. Also useSomeStore is technically a composable too and has "use" prefix, but it can be used directly in other stores

So for pinia store function it's const partialStore = useMyPartial() and then augment it the way you need. Or if multiple stores are very similar, it could be createMyStore factory function with parameters that calls defineStore inside. That's how I'd approach it, both ways will have no problems with TS.

As for the classes for reusable code, they have multiple problems with vue reactivity, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76247596/3731501 , and you'd have to write a lot of boilerplate code like "myValue" to wrap them like you tried, which is not optimal. As for writable computeds and other apis that aren't suited for the use in stores, it's possible to use them with pinia but they need to reside in separate helpers outside stores to transform a store to consume it in a suitable way, e.g. pinia's own storeToRefs
