can not set instance of a class to a reactive ref
As shown in the code posted below,in file.js section mentioned below, it shows the code of .js file. i am trying to instantiate an object of the class WSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses and assign it to the reactive ref #wsFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses.
at run time, the .catch of the promise is called due to the following two lines of code:
this.#wsFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses.value = new WSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses();
this.#wsFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses.value.setResponse(response);

to solve this issue, i changes the code to be as follows:
new WSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses().setResponse(response);

and it works without any errors. it seems that assigning a object reference to a reactive ref causes this issue.
would you please tell me why code in the file.js section causes an error and how to fix it
file.js:
constructor(clsDigitizationPolygonInteractionsInst) {
    this.#wsFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses = ref(null);
}

this.#wsSentinelhubEngineProcessor.fetchNDVIsTIFF(res => {
    const response = JSON.parse(res);
            
    this.#wsFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses.value = new WSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses();
    this.#wsFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses.value.setResponse(response);
    
    return response;
})
.then(res => {

WSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses:
export class WSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses {
    #msg = null;
    #response = null;

    constructor() {
        this.#response = ref(null);
    }

    setResponse(res) {
        this.#response.value = res;
    }


"causes an error" - which error exactly? The question lacks clear problem statement. Reactive classes and the use of refs are a known pitfall because of ref unwrapping. Ref unwrapping could be prevented with the use of native private fields, but the problem is that reactive proxies aren't class instances and can't access private fields. Here the problem could probably be fixed with #wsFetchNDVIsTIFFResponses = shallowRef(null), but generally reactive classes are a big footgun in vue that can rarely be justified

@EstusFlask by “cause an error” I ment that the “.catch” is executed due to the execution of two problematic line of code mentioned above are. What does “foot gun” mean please?I can not find any translation to it

Which error in .catch exactly? I suspect it's related to private field access but the question needs to be specific on it. Sorry, that's dev idiom, a device that can damage the one who uses it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73940781/3731501 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/67895251/3731501 , for example. The problem with private fields can be added to this list

@EstusFlask the error message is not indicative
